# Python regex negation

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Below are few example strings

`as-jfk-interface-module-trojan-7.100.110-12350009`

`network-refresh-core-3.3.909-99950009`

`network-challenge7-7-ui-module-8.23.590-12350009`

and I use the following regex to get the version part of the string like `7.100.110-12350009`

regex:

`(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))?(?:\-([\w][\w\.\-_]*))?)?`

While trying to match the word portion like `as-jfk-interface-module-trojan` or `network-challenge7-7-ui-module` by negation,
`[^(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))?(?:\-([\w][\w\.\-_]*))?)?]`, it says **Invalid regular expression: unbalanced parenthesis**

```
st = "as-jfk-interface-module-trojan-7.100.110-12350009"
pattern = "(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:\.(0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))?(?:\-([\w][\w\.\-_]*))?)?"
re.search(pattern, st)
```

What am I doing incorrect ?

Comment: You have two extra/unmatched parenthesis after `\d*`

Comment: See for yourself: https://regex101.com/r/kKGPmw/1 (top-right)

Comment: The error Python shows also says "at position 16", which should be enough to go off of.

Comment: Yes, If I correct the parenthesis, even the version part is not matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negated character class doesn't work like that!

`[^abc]` is exactly the same as `[^cba]`, it means match a character that is not `a` or `b` or `c`. It doesn't mean: don't match `abc`.

To get the word portion you could use for example

```py
r"[a-z\d-]+(?=-\d\.)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VScode, install "reg exp explain" addon. It will show you in graphical way,your reg exp and can see what is wrong.

Comment: In my opinion this should be a comment (after correcting the typo in your one and only sentence).